# Converting a single col into mutiple rows (GNUPLOT file)

Tags: bash, gnuplot, rows

I'm trying to make a gnuplot picture from a file, have a problem with the distribution of `'data.txt'` file. The actual distribution is :

```
1 4  x1 
1 16 x2
4 4  x3
4 16 x4
8 4  x5
8 16 x6
```

The first line makes reference to the number of lines that i want, and the other colums make reference to the x and y axis.

I'm trying two approximations to make the picture without success:

1. Use some gnuplot function to sketch the picture using the actual distribution that my file have. I have not found this command.
2. Make a bash script to convert the actual file into another with the correct distribution

> `4   x1   x3   x5
>
>   16  x2   x4   x6`

Comment: I haven't understood yet what you need the first column for. In your example I could deduce the desired output just using the second and third columns. Is your example too symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing #2

```
awk '{a[$2] = a[$2] $3 " "} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
```

```
4 x1 x3 x5
16 x2 x4 x6
```